# angular/node with passport: passport says android is not authenticated, but browser works fine

Tags: android, angularjs, node.js, video, passport.js

So this is pretty weird.

I am running an app with angular, node and passport.
It's managing some information and you can view a video associated with it.

When I use the app in the browser, all seems to work fine. But when I access the app with an android phone browser (didn't test with iOS), I can login and all works fine, but when I access the video (in the same session!) passport denies access! I am baffled as the rest of the application works fine in the android browser...

routes:

```
app.all('*',ensureAuthenticated)

app.get('/ping', routes.ping)
app.get('/logout', routes.logout)
app.get('/start', routes.start)
#more routes
app.get('/videos/:name', can_view_video, media.play) #can_view_video checks if a user has the rights to see the video

#Middleware to check that a user is authenticated
ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) ->
      if (req.isAuthenticated())
          return next()
      logger.debug("Not authenticated!")
      res.redirect('/')

#Middleware to check that user can view video
can_view_video = (req, res, next) ->
    url = req.url
    url_params_only = url.substring("/videos/".length)
    id = url_params_only.substring(0, url_params_only.indexOf("/"))
    can_access(req, res, id, (err) ->
      if err?
        handle_error(err, err.message, res)
      else
        return next()
    )

can_access = (req, res, id=null, next) ->
  role = req.user.role
  if id is null
    id = req.params.userId
  user_id = req.user.id
  User.findOne({ user_id:id }, (err, user) ->
    if err?
      handle_error(err, err.message, res)
    if not user?
      text = "no user with that id"
      handle_error(err, text, res)
    else if not id == user_id or role is not "admin"
      text = "no user with that id"
      logger.debug(text)
      handler_error(new Error(text), text, res)
    else
      logger.debug "Login: can access, ok"
      next()
    )
```

play the video:

```
exports.play = (req,res) ->
    video_path = __dirname + "/media/" + req.user.id + "/" + req.params.video

    fs.readFile(video_path, (err, data) ->
        if err?
          handle_error(err, "video can't be read", res)
        else
            range = req.headers.range
            if range?
                total = data.length

                parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
                partialstart = parts[0]
                partialend = parts[1]

                start = parseInt(partialstart, 10)
                end = if partialend then parseInt(partialend, 10) else total-1

                chunksize = (end-start)+1

                res.writeHead(206, 
                    "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
                    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes", 
                    "Content-Length": chunksize, 
                    "Content-Type": 'video/mp4' )
            else
                logger.debug("no range")
                res.writeHead(200,
                    "Content-Length": data.length,
                    "Content-Type": 'video/mp4')                
            res.end(data)
    )
```

The output when accessing with the android browser is:

```
no range
Not authenticated!
```

EDIT: If I remove the passport authentication, the video can be displayed on the phone...

EDIT2: on request: the serialize functions

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) ->
      done(null, user._id)
)

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) ->
      User.findById(id, (err, user) ->
         done(err, user)
      )
)
```

So it seems the code runs fine, the video gets loaded and returned to the browser, but it cannot play it for whatever weird reason which is pretty puzzling for me...

In a normal desktop browser (e.g. Chrome), I get a range in the headers, then the video returns and it gets played - no "Not authenticated!" message!

Comment: post `can_view_video` plz

Comment: @Plato there you are. I don't think there's an issue there though.

Comment: probably not... how about your `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser` functions? and are you putting passport ahead of app.router in the middlewware stack?

Comment: also i dunno if `can_access = (req, res, id=null, next)` is a coffeescript shortcut but ECMAscript 5 does not let you assign default values like that

Comment: I added the passport functions in EDIT2; yes, passport.initialize() and passport.session() come before app.router

Comment: What's really weird is why would it work consistently on a desktop browser and fail consistently on an android browser?

Comment: Dunno, maybe the android browser has broken session handling? Have you tried more than one android browsers?

Comment: I discovered that for some reason, there is a different session ID in passport at the point where the user clicks on viewing the video...why would that be???

Comment: I tested with android's browser and also with chrome for android - same behavior. I also changed and updated the angular versions to 1.2.22 from 1.2.16 and same behavior. Why the heck would android browsers change the session ID??? It's a great mystery to me...

Comment: I dunno, I'm all guessed out! sorry, good luck :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the potential problem could be here:

```
res.writeHead(206, 
                    "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
                    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes", 
                    "Content-Length": chunksize, 
                    "Content-Type": 'video/mp4' )
...

res.end(data)
```

We are telling the header here that we send a chunk, but are actually sending the whole file...

From [here](http://blog.dojchinovski.mk/?p=41) I found the way to do that correctly:

```
res.end(data.slice(start, end+1), "binary");
```

This seems to improve things a lot but we'll need to check further